# Strapi integration with Builder.io

Tags: integration, strapi, builder.io

I am trying to find any plugin/provider which can integrate Builder.io with Strapi or any other helpful links that can anyone share.

Answer (score 1):

With Builder.io, you can create your custom plugin. I would recommend a data connector plugin:
Data connector plugins are a way to enrich the data available in the editor sections and pages from external sources. Once linked to a data source, users can pick and choose entries or query that source and bind to the results of those queries directly in builder. Resources:

Please see this reference for more information on how to create a custom data connector plugin: https://github.com/BuilderIO/builder/blob/main/plugins/contributing.md#data-connector-plugins